# Hive query : Ambiguous column reference acct_nbr in stage

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I getting "Ambiguous column reference"

query  :

```
SELECT stage.acct_nbr 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   mem stage 
               JOIN (SELECT acct_nbr, 
                            corp_ent_cd, 
                            sub_seq_nbr, 
                            mem_nbr, 
                            Max(cdc_src_last_updt_ts) AS cdc_src_last_updt_ts 
                     FROM   mem 
                     WHERE  file_nm = 'DLTV.FULL.MES3191.D180423' 
                     GROUP  BY acct_nbr, 
                               corp_ent_cd, 
                               sub_seq_nbr, 
                               mem_nbr) c 
                 ON c.corp_ent_cd = stage.corp_ent_cd 
                    AND c.acct_nbr = stage.acct_nbr 
                    AND c.sub_seq_nbr = stage.sub_seq_nbr 
                    AND c.mem_nbr = stage.mem_nbr 
                    AND stage.cdc_src_last_updt_ts = c.cdc_src_last_updt_ts 
        WHERE  stage.file_nm = 'DLTV.FULL.MES3191.D180423') stage;
```

**Error Message:**

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10007]: Ambiguous column reference acct_nbr in stage (state=42000,code=10007)

Whereas if I do select * instead of select stage.acct_nbr, it is executing without error.

Could somebody solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on `SELECT *`.

There are two column at subquery `c.acct_nbr` ,`stage.acct_nbr` ,so outer `SELECT` can't `stage.acct_nbr` distinguish which colunm you want to get.

So you can choose `c.acct_nbr` or `stage.acct_nbr` in your `select` subquery

You can try this.

```
SELECT stage.acct_nbr 
FROM   (SELECT c.acct_nbr 
        FROM   mem stage 
               JOIN (SELECT acct_nbr, 
                            corp_ent_cd, 
                            sub_seq_nbr, 
                            mem_nbr, 
                            Max(cdc_src_last_updt_ts) AS cdc_src_last_updt_ts 
                     FROM   mem 
                     WHERE  file_nm = 'DLTV.FULL.MES3191.D180423' 
                     GROUP  BY acct_nbr, 
                               corp_ent_cd, 
                               sub_seq_nbr, 
                               mem_nbr) c 
                 ON c.corp_ent_cd = stage.corp_ent_cd 
                    AND c.acct_nbr = stage.acct_nbr 
                    AND c.sub_seq_nbr = stage.sub_seq_nbr 
                    AND c.mem_nbr = stage.mem_nbr 
                    AND stage.cdc_src_last_updt_ts = c.cdc_src_last_updt_ts 
        WHERE  stage.file_nm = 'DLTV.FULL.MES3191.D180423') stage;
```